# Twitter Bootstrap - How to start dropdown close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

So first of all, here's the link to my site: http://songfreek.com/

This is what my sidebar dropdown navigation is doing:

[image]

This is what I'd like my sidebar dropdown navigation to do:

[image]

I guess I'll explain it if it's not obvious: I only want the "User" tab to automatically start opened upon the loading of the page, instead of them all opening.

Here's the code (which repeats for each tab, just different content):

```
`<li class="nav-header has_submenu">
                            <a href="#">
                                User <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul style="list-style: none;">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>Messages <span class="badge badge-info">4</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cogs"></i>Settings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-comment"></i>Shoutbox</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>Staff List</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-flag"></i>My Infractions</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i>Rules & Regulations</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-off"></i>Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>`
```

So what can I change the code to to make it load opened, or closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap `data-toggle="collapse"` to toggle the menus. Each menu `UL` would have `class="collapse"` and a unique ID that can be assigned to the `data-target` attribute of the link that toggles the menu...

Use `class="collapse in"` to have the user menu open first.

```
<li class="nav-header">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#userMenu">
    User <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
  </a>
  <ul style="list-style: none;" class="collapse in" id="userMenu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>Messages <span class="badge badge-info">4</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cogs"></i>Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-comment"></i>Shoutbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>Staff List</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-flag"></i>My Infractions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i>Rules &amp; Regulations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-off"></i>Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-header">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#radioDJMenu">
    Radio DJ <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
  </a>
  <ul style="list-style: none;" class="collapse" id="radioDJMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Information &amp; Stats</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DJ Says</a></li>

    .
    .
    .
```

### [**Demo**](http://bootply.com/61710)